# Nuget Cannot find system packages

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, webforms, nuget

I have a webforms application that builds and runs on localhost without difficulties but fails to do so when publishing to an azure web app as it gives the following errors:

```
  Severity Code Description Project File Line   Suppression State Error NuGet Package restore failed for project OpenRep: Unable to find version '4.0.11' of package 'System.Text.Trim().Encoding'.
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'System.Text.Trim().Encoding.4.0.11' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json: Package 'System.Text.Trim().Encoding.4.0.11' is not found on source 'https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json'.
  https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/: Package 'System.Text.Trim().Encoding.4.0.11' is not found on source 'https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/curated-feeds/microsoftdotnet/'.
```

I have tried reinstalling packages on the nuget package manager console but this won't work either. I also thought that the system packages came default with VS.

Comment: are these packages required ? is the project.json file having only the necessary package references?

Comment: Are you sure `System.Text.Trim().Encoding` is the name of the package? There is a `Trim` method in `System` and you are correct that it shouldn't need to be downloaded from NuGet on deploy. I'm not seeing any packages in the main NuGet sources that have that name so maybe you need to set up the source first so the package can be found.

Comment: Please make sure you are reference the correct package names in packages.config file and share your packages.config file content here. And check whether the azure web app has enable nuget packages restore and the nuget.config file has added into azure web app too.

Comment: Can you share the detailed steps to reproduce this issue?